# Bad Request Error HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, httpclient

I have the following implementation. It works actually. However, when I restart wcf service and call the HTTPClient again as follows, then I get a bad request error.

**Error message:**

```
StatusCode: 400,  
ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request',  
Version: 1.1, 
Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 
Headers: { cache-control: private transfer-encoding: chunked server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 x-aspnet-version: 4.0.30319 x-sourcefiles:
=?UTF-8?B?QsrdfeterRk1cU2VydmVyXEFwcGxpY2F0aW9uIFNlcnZlclxGaWVsZCBSZXBvcnRlclxPcHNDZW50ZXIuTW9iaWxlLlN5bmNcTW9iaWxlRmllbGRTZXJ2aWNlLnN2Y1xEb3d511454eredefew==?= x-powered-by: ASP.NET date: Tue, 06 Feb 2018 16:54:43 GMT connection: close content-type: text/html }}
```

**Code implementation**

```
private static T GoRequest<T>(string url, Dictionary<string, object> parameters, HttpMethod method, string body = "") where T : class
{
   using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()))
   {
     var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri);
     if (body != string.Empty)
     {
        request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
     }

      try
      {
        using (var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer lies in the wcf server. What did you find when you debugged it?

Comment: Bad Request means the server didn't like the data you sent to it. We have no way of knowing the server's requirements or what data you are sending. If there is documentation for the service, review it.

Comment: @Will, if I do not restart wcf, it works. But when restart wcf, then it gives me that error. This call does not even reach out to wcf to track. I wonder I am missing anything in my current implementation?

Comment: I don't see how this would result in a 400 response, but you should not block on async calls with `.Result`. You should make all your code async or use a synchronous API like `HttpWebRequest`. Do that and see if the behavior changes.

Comment: @Crowcoder, could you please illustrate with an example?

Comment: To use [WebRequest look here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-request-data-using-the-webrequest-class). And [this is a good start](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) into async. The thing about async is you must craft your code to support it "all the way down" and it is impossible for me to tell if you will be able to do that.

Comment: I suspect one of two things 1) A cookie issue 2) The server doesn't allow more than one connection from a client.  So you are attempting to connect a second time without closing first connection.  The "new HttpClient" should close the first connection so maybe you need to add a wait to make sure the connection closes.

Comment: @jdweng Could you please elaborate cookie issue? If that is the issue, how could I able to fix? By the way, I do not pass or use any cookies. For the second issue, I have `new`  as follows `var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler())`

Comment: A cookie gets established the first time you make a connection.  It is used so the server knows that a client previously connected so less info needs to be transferred.  The client stores downloaded data in the users temp folder.  The Net Library will automatically add add to the http headers the cookie id if one exists for the server.  So the server checks the cookie and client IP address and may give an error if they are not correct.  Cookies have timeout periods so when the timeout occurs you will be able to connect. You can delete the cookies manually by using your IE and delete history.

Comment: Is there a way that I can clear cookies in the code?